# Java equality integer

Tags: java

I find it kind of confusing, I'm trying to solve this problem I found on the Internet as my programming exercise:

Implement a class with methods which takes one INTEGER parameter "initialValue" and returns following:

a. if initialValue is equal to 1 - return 2 (INTEGER) 
b. if initialValue is equal to 2 - return 1 (INTEGER)

This is what I've done so far:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.print(myMethod(1));

}

private static int myMethod(int initialValue) {
    int n = 1;
    if(initialValue == n) {
        return 2;
    } else {
        return n;
    }
}
```

But I guess this is a basic solution. Do you know any method variations other than this? Thanks.

Comment: What is the expected output for initialValue = 3? That else will set the result to 1 for any value apart from 1.

Comment: using ternary operator, `return initialValue == 1 ? 2 : 1;`

Comment: @Jonjongot : but it will return 1  for other than 2 also..

Comment: @Prashant well, that is not included in the OP's requirement

Comment: Does that task call for an `Integer` object or primitive `int` as parameter? If the task is to use `Integer`, it becomes more interesting, as you probably want to compare using `equals()` rather than `==` (object equality vs identity).

Answer (score 4):

little fancy solution would be doing [XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) with `3`

```
return initialValue ^ 3;
```

Comment: thanks this is cool one-liner solution :) I almost forgot about XOR

Comment: Slightly clearer (IMO) would be `return 3-initialValue;`  Most of us deal better with normal arithmetic than bit math.  This cute but tricky answer should not have so many upvotes.

Comment: Ah if you put that as an answer earlier. @PM77-1

Answer (score 3):

You might use the conditional operator `?:`  and something like

```
private static int myMethod(int initialValue) {
    return initialValue == 1 ? 2 : 1;
}
```

The ternary operator is described in the [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) like

> Another conditional operator is `?:`, which can be thought of as shorthand for an if-then-else statement (discussed in the [Control Flow Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/flow.html) section of this lesson). This operator is also known as the ternary operator because it uses three operands. In the following example, this operator should be read as: "If someCondition is true, assign the value of value1 to result. Otherwise, assign the value of value2 to result."

Answer (score 1):

I really hope that you plan on using this for learning only not to hand in as your own work. Your way works very well. However, you could also use the modulo operator (assuming of course that the only two inputs would be 1 and 2).

```
private static int myMethod(int initialValue) {
    return initialValue % 2 + 1;
}
```

Best of luck with your CS aspirations!

Answer (score 0):

It can also be done this way,

```
private static int myMethod(int initialValue) {
    switch (initialValue){
         case 1:
             return 2;
         case 2:
             return 1;
         default:
             return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe even hints need to be syntactically correct

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
int input;
// code for input value 
System.out.print(myMethod(input));

}

private static int myMethod(int initialValue) {
   int n = 1;
   if(initialValue == n) {
    return 2;
   } else if(initialValue==2) {
    return 1;
   }
   else {
    return initialValue;
   } 
}
```

This might give better output if you insert values dynamically